ComfyUI RIFE VFI error tried all GitHub base urls to download but no success?
I'm working with https://github.com/Fannovel16/ComfyUI-Frame-Interpolation in ComfyUI and I get the following error when attempting to use the RIFE VFI node in this basic setup:

Error occurred when executing RIFE VFI:
Tried all GitHub base urls to download rife49.pth but no suceess.
Below is the error log:
Error when downloading from:
https://github.com/styler00dollar/VSGAN-tensorrt-docker/releases/download/models/rife49.pth


Worth noting I am on a Mac, but this doesn't appear to be a problem with Mac so much as unable to find any of the rife .pth files. I have manually downloaded rife49.pth but am unsure where in the ComfyUI-Frame-Interpolation folder structure I would put it:

How can I fix this so that I can use the RIFE VFI node?

Here ComfyUI\custom_nodes\ComfyUI-Frame-Interpolation\ckpts\rife

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
